# Remember me in Login with Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I tried remember me with session but I can not succeed. First of all is it possible?

in CheckedChanged method

```
     if (CheckBox1.Checked)
    {
        Session["email"] = TextBox1.Text;
        Session["pass"] = TextBox2.Text;

    }
```

in pageload method

```
     if (Session["email"].ToString() !=null && Session["pass"].ToString() !=null)
    {
       TextBox1.Text = Session["email"].ToString();
        TextBox2.Text = Session["pass"].ToString();
    }
```

but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use `Session` for this purpose. You should have to use `Cookie` to save the `Remember Me` status.

Answer (score 3):

"Remember me" functionality is implemented by using persistent cookie.

You can't use Session object, because it will be automatically deleted after certain period of user inactivity.

**Security note**: **Never** store user password in plaintext format!

Answer (score 0):

Btw: its better that you create a user class with two properties `email` and `pass`, and store that in one session element:

```
User myUser = new User();
myUser.Email = "test@test.com";
myUser.Pass = "123456";

session["user"] = myUser;
```

and you store the *Remember me* inside a cookie, with some credentials highly encrypted or salted hash, so when your user visits again you match the name and salted hash with the info you have in your database

Comment: and if You want the user object from the session You use User myUser = session["user"] as User and then check if the myUser is not null

Comment: Please, use proper english, i.e. "you" and "your" instead of "u" and "ur"/"yr". It's fine if someone's english is not that good because he isn't a native speaker but these chat/texting-style shortcuts are not appreciated here.

Answer (score -1):

change like this. as you are checking for the value. you cant access ToString() method , when null object is there .

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["email"]) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["pass"])) )
 // then do with session objects.
```

Comment: Then maybe string.IsNullOrEmpty is better?

Comment: -1, calling `.ToString()` on something that doesn't exist in the session will throw a null reference exception.

Comment: If you call ToString() you are never going to have a null value. Everything in .net has a string representation. But be careful you can not call ToString() on null!

Comment: @JamesHill check updated answer, even i mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Ravi, Your updated code still doesn't allow for `email` or `pass` to be non-existent in the session. Shouldn't you check to see if it exists before you `.ToString()` it?